# How to upload receipts on Quickbooks online using rest api?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am developing an android app using Quickbooks rest API. Where I want to upload a receipt on Quickbooks using my app - Idea is to capture the receipt/ image and then upload it on the server the same as Quickbook's Android app does.

But the challenge is I am not able to find any rest API endpoints, using that I can upload a receipt at Quickbook's Receipt tab.

I am not sure about the [sales receipt](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/salesreceipt), is it the same as a receipt?

Note - I am able to upload a document on Quickbooks but it does not appear at Quickbooks Receipt tab and I already know how to upload it by mail or Quickbooks android app or via drag & drop.

Here is what I have tried -

- Asked a [question](https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/feed/0D54R000072yHDwSAM) at developer form
- [This](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/attachable) is how we can upload a document on quickbook